# Update only passed parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

There is a way to update only passed parameters and leave unchanged the others? I'm looking for a way to avoid query building on the fly. e.g. I want to change description field and leave email unchanged:

```
$MyArray['email']='';
$MyArray['description']='The new description';

$Result = pg_query_params($db,'UPDATE users SET email=$1, description=$2 WHERE id = $3', array($MyArray['email'],$MyArray['description'],$User['id']));
```

Thanks
D

Comment: @Isfirs and LuckyBurger: The problem is after identified what update, it is: how update what identified without build a specific query on the fly and without impacting other fields and using pg_query_params.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **easy** way... SQL doesn't have this feature, but you can do it in a simple fashion in your application logic.

1. In your form serialize the original instance data

   serialize($myDataArray)
2. Once you post the updates, compare it to the serialized data

   deserialize($myDataArray);

   $diff = array_diff($original, $modified);

This should give you an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I did, you can build a little wrapper to check changed values.

Kind like this method out of a class i use:

```
    /**
     * Checks for changes between $old and $new.
     * All arrays must be assoc.
     *
     * The keys of $map are the keys of $old and the values of $map are the keys of $new:
     * $map: key => $old[key]
     * $map: val => $new[key]
     *
     * The return is an array with $old keys and $new values.
     *
     * @param array $old
     * @param array $new
     * @param array $map
     */
    public function checkChanges(array $old, array $new, array $map) {
        $toReturn = array();

        foreach ($map as $oldKey=>$newKey) {
            if ($old[$oldKey] != $new[$newKey]) {
                if (is_string($new[$newKey])) {
                    $toReturn[$oldKey] = "'".$new[$newKey]."'";
                } else {
                    $toReturn[$oldKey] = $new[$newKey];
                }
            }
        }

        if (count ($toReturn) == 0 ) {
            return null;
        }

        return $toReturn;
    }
```

The first array contains the old unchanged values. the second one the new changed and unchanged values (depends on your or yor users input) and the last one will keep the arraykeys as keys for the first array while you use the value as keys for the second array.

This will be a PHP only solution and it works for me since i will only update those values.

NOTE: It will not work with nested arrays. If you ahve multiple arrays you have to work it out yourself.